# MDX Query with 2 Row Items

Tags: mdx

I would like to see what the Max order date is on all of my clients.
1 - How do I put two row items into a query.
2 - How do I get the Max Date.
3 - I also don't want Amount in the query, but it looks as if MDX requires a Column for a query to run.

Below is an attempt at this query.

```
Select [Measures].[Amount] On Columns,
[Dim Customer].[Cust #],Max([Dim Inv Date].[Actual Date]).MEMBERS ON ROWS
from [OperationsFinance]
```

Answer (score 0):

It is possible to have empty columns:

```
Select 
    {} On Columns,
    [Dim Customer].[Cust #].MEMBERS ON ROWS
FROM [OperationsFinance]
```

To put two rows you need to `crossjoin` - either with the crossjoin function or the asterisk operator. Try the following example - you might need to uncomment the `NON EMPTY` function to get rid of nulls created from the cross-join:

```
Select 
    [Measures].[Amount] 
On Columns,

//NON EMPTY
    [Dim Customer].[Cust #] 
    *
    [Dim Inv Date].[Actual Date].MEMBERS 
ON ROWS
from [OperationsFinance]
```

To do the `Max` date I can see the following example against the Adv Works cube. This is taken from the MDX book by Tomislav Piasevoli:

```
WITH 
MEMBER [Measures].[Max_Date2] AS
    MAX (
        EXISTING [Date].[Date].[Date].MEMBERS, 
        IIF([Measures].[Internet Sales Amount] = 0,
            NULL,
            [Date].[Date].CURRENTMEMBER.MEMBERVALUE
            )
    )
SELECT 

    {[Measures].[Internet Sales Amount], 
    [Measures].[Max_Date]} ON 0,

NON EMPTY
    {
    [Promotion].[Promotion].MEMBERS
    *
    [Date].[Calendar Year].MEMBERS
    }
ON 1

FROM [Adventure Works]
```

Adapting to you:

```
WITH
MEMBER [Measures].[Max_Date] AS
    MAX (
        EXISTING [Dim Inv Date].[Actual Date].MEMBERS, 
        IIF([Measures].[Amount] = 0,
            NULL,
            [Dim Inv Date].[Actual Date].CURRENTMEMBER.MEMBERVALUE
            )
    )
SELECT 

    {[Measures].[Amount], 
    [Measures].[Max_Date]} ON 0,

NON EMPTY
    {
    [Dim Customer].[Cust #].MEMBERS
    *
    [Dim Inv Date].[Actual Date].MEMBERS
    }
ON 1

FROM [OperationsFinance]
```

Comment: whytheq... Thank You very much. This has been super helpful!

Comment: @davidhall80  - excellent: more importantly did it answer the question?